# Remote event receiver IIS website Anonymous access

Tags: anonymous-authentication, remote-event-receiver, high-trust-app

For On-premise  environment high-trust app -

We are creating a remote event receiver and handling the "App Installed" and "App uninstalling" events. When we try to install the app it fails with the error

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

This has been posted in a couple of forums and there are only a handful of blogs that explain- IIS website that hosts the remote event receiver web service should have "Anonymous authentication" enabled, atleast the service should be if not the entire website.

But I could not find a substantial explanation why this is required. Since SharePoint calls the web service, it needs anonymous access enabled ? And is this a necessary setting to make the remote event receivers work ?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing the same issue.